# IE7 CSS :first-child Selector with Media Query

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

I have the following CSS in a media-query (for min-width 768px):

```
.formHolder-section {width: 235px; position: relative; float: left; margin:0;}
.formHolder-section:first-child { margin: 0 20px 0 40px; }
```

The override (for :first-child) works in all browsers except IE7. I'm wondering if there's any good reason for this... I also tried reversing the margin value (applying it to all (2) .formHolder-section divs, then using a different selector:

```
.formHolder-section {width: 235px; position: relative; float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 40px;}
.formHolder-section + .formHolder-section { margin: 0; }
```

This also did NOT work. I've solved my issue by just giving both divs some margin (as opposed to only the first div). The odd thing is... all other CSS works in here except for the first-child selector. I'm wondering if anyone has any idea what could be the cause of the issue.

Here's some of the HTML (though, again, the HTML/CSS works everywhere except IE7):

```
<div class="formContainer">
    <div class="formHolder-section">
        <span class="form-required">*Denotes field as required</span>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
                <label>First:*</label>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-input-full" name="firstName" id="firstName">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Last:*</label>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-input-full" name="lastName" id="lastName">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Email Address:*</label>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-input-full" name="email" id="email">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="listOptionPadding">Are you 18 years old?*</label>
                <input type="radio" value="true" class="form-radio" name="over18" id="over181"> <span class="italic">Yes</span>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" value="true" class="form-radio" name="over18" id="over182"> <span class="italic">No</span>
            </li>
            [...]
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="formHolder-section">
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
                <label class="listOptionPaddingBottom">When Do You Intend to Purchase a New Vehicle?</label>
                <input type="radio" value="1_MONTH" class="form-radio" name="nextPurchase" id="nextPurchase1"> <span class="italic">Within a Month</span>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" value="3_MONTH" class="form-radio" name="nextPurchase" id="nextPurchase2"> <span class="italic">Within the next 3 Months</span>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" value="6_MONTH" class="form-radio" name="nextPurchase" id="nextPurchase3"> <span class="italic">Within the next 6 Months</span>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" value="WITHIN_YEAR" class="form-radio" name="nextPurchase" id="nextPurchase4"> <span class="italic">Within a Year</span>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" value="OVER_YEAR" class="form-radio" name="nextPurchase" id="nextPurchase5"> <span class="italic">More than 1 Year</span>
            </li>
            <li class="interested-in">
                <label>What Toyota vehicles are you interested in?</label>
            </li>
            [...]
        </ul>       
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="form-button rounded">
        <a class="form-terms" href="/ToyotaMotorApp/mobile/tyw/terms.html">View all the terms and conditions</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the DOCTYPE (using HTML5 here -- I've seen some weird stuff with quirksmode, no doubt -- but, don't think this is the issue here). Using modernizer for media queries (this is a responsive site):

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

- by the way, I took this from IE8 (so the html tag would be different for IE7 -- but, I'm testing in a different VM right now).

Comment: What doctype are you using, and can you please post part of the HTML that contains the `.formHolder-section` divs?

Comment: Can you show your media queries? Are you using any scripts to allow IE7 and IE8 to read media queries (Modernizr does *not* polyfill support, only test for it)?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response to your comment. Here is the media query used to contain the above CSS: @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { [...] }. However, once again, IE was picking up the styles in this section (for example, the selector before either the :first-child or X + X selectors works just fine -- as well as all other CSS in that query).

Comment: It seems that only the sibling and pseudo selectors didn't work within the media query(/ies). Outside of that scope (query), they do work.

Answer (score 0):

Two words - quirks mode. The first-child pseudo selector doesn't really work well until you get to IE9.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17

Comment: Not really an answer. Great site (I use it all the time), but doesn't apply to this particular issue. :first-child works elsewhere in the CSS. I'm looking for an exact reason -- not "it doesn't work well until you're at version 9". I use :first-child in IE quite often without issue. So, I'm wondering what the problem here is... in case maybe someone's seen an issue with media queries, especially.

Comment: Also, please make note that I eliminated the :first-child selector and the second CSS line (the override) didn't work (see 2nd css example above)! So, this isn't specific to the selector (but, instead, an immediate margin override).

Comment: The second example uses next-sibling (+) instead of first-child which also has issues until you get to IE9: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t12. Quirks mode is a way of life, and there are so many different ways to do the same thing that you should be able to get the job done.

Comment: Your two sentences don't seem to connect with each other - in quirks mode, `:first-child` doesn't work in **any version of IE** (and neither does `+`). The bugs associated with IE7/8 and those two selectors have nothing to do with quirks mode, and in fact they exhibit those bugs even in standards mode, where they're expected to work.